# Logo not loading on shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use shiny for the first time to build a very simple web app.

I would like to add a logo on the left hand corner of my dashboard but failing to load the pic

this is what I have written:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title=tags$img(src='logo.jpg')),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
  )
)
```

This is the structure of my folder

```
GH
-->model
---->app
------>webapp
       server.R
       ui.R
--> pictures
    logo.jpg
```

If I run my app I get a question mark as a placeholder of the actual picture

Comment: rename the folder `pictures` to `www`

Comment: @PorkChop still seeing the question mark placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forcing it with `addResourcePath(prefix, path)`, and then use `src =  "prefix/logo.jpg"`

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(){
    addResourcePath("www", "www")
    tagList(
        dashboardPage(
            dashboardHeader(title = tags$img( src='www/logo.png') ),
            dashboardSidebar(),
            dashboardBody()
        )  
    )
}


server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks, seemed to work. Is there anyway to extend this to picture file names that are assigned through the server function?

Comment: If it solves the issue, feel free to accept the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 
For your new question, this pattern can be reused with any combinaison of folders and files